# Understanding the difference between union and symmetric difference of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Set Theory, Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets. Now, we denote an element which is either in $A$ or in $B$ as $A\cup B$. And an element which is in both $A$ and $B$ as $A\cap B$. But I can't understand why we denote an element which is either in $A$ or in $B$ as $A\cup B$? I think it should be denoted by $A\Delta B$ because $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. Because $(A\setminus B)$ includes all the elements of $A$ which are not in $B$ and $(B\setminus A)$ includes all the elements of B which are not in $A$. Please help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: Points which are either in $A$ or $B$ or both is $A \cup B$.  Points which are either in $A$ or $B$ but not both is $A \Delta B$.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much @geetha290krm

Comment: But one thing @geetha290krm, you mentioned that elements which are either in A or B or both is $A\cup B$. But elements which are in both A and B are denoted by $A\cap B$. Please check your definition once. I am also very much confused.

Comment: $A\cup B$ includes $A \cap B$ also. Nothing wrong with what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an incorrect understanding of union. $A \cup B = \{x : x \in A \vee x \in B \}$ consists of all elements that are in $A$ or $B$, **including** all elements in both $A$ and $B$ (see Venn diagram below). In short, the "or" of union is an inclusive or.

[image]

$A \Delta B = \{x : x \in A \oplus x \in B \}$ consists of all elements that are in either $A$ or $B$, containing no elements in both $A$ and $B$ (see Venn diagram below). In short, the "or" of symmetric difference is an exclusive or.

[image]

Thus, whenever $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, we have $A \cup B \neq A \Delta B$, and vice versa.

Comment: How you have drawn the Venn diagrams @RyRy the Fly Guy?

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti the Venn diagrams above are images I found online and included in my response.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti i don't know what you're referring to when you ask "why you edited the $-$ sign with \$\$?" I don't have a minus sign anywhere in my response. Typically, \$\$ is used to demarcate Latex code in the text editor.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti if you're happy with my answer to your post, then please click the green check mark to close your question. Thanks!

Comment: OK. Thank you very much @RyRy the Fly Guy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common doubt among many beginners of set theory.

Do not get confused with words in: "an element which is either in A or in B". The use of "either/or" in everyday English is usually divisive, and meant to imply there are only two options: A or B, but not both A and B. However, the use of "either A or B" in mathematics allows the option that both A and B hold (i.e. A∪B includes A∩B).
Therefore, while using AΔB, we specify by saying 'only in A or in B but not in both A and B.